# How to prevent large groups of animals from destroying my land?

Tags: biology, magic, environment

I've created a world that is filled with beings and creatures that are very specific that can be easily separated and recognized. In this world there are seven (7) basic types of lifeforms (not counting bacteria, viruses and other micro-organisms). Basic differences are their food sources.

Types:

- **Rocky family** - mainly eat plants and feed on magic-like energy that is all around them in nature.
- **Humans** - eat normal human food ( meat, plants, etc.)
- **Basic animals** - ( animals that are a food source for humans ), grass and low bushes
- **Nature protector animals** - ( These animals are not a food source for humans and have been given some magical powers and serve to protect the nature ) Eat small "Basic animal" and live on the energy provided by the magic in the air
- **Phantoms** eat anything except plants, and cannot live on the magical energy
- **Live plants** mostly act like "sand traps" eating any flesh

The final category is a creature that is made from a colony of small magical creatures. They eat any kind of plants or animals, and are parasitic and can swarm like or locusts.

**I need to somehow limit them from destroying a large amount of land.**

My current idea is that they should only be active at specific times of the year.

Is this a viable solution to reasonably prevent these types of creatures from destroying my world?

Comment: Hello. First, I believe this is on topic. Given how readily I vote off-topic, it has to count for something ;) But then - it looks broad/opinion based. Format of this site assumes one clear question and answers that may be good or bad. You seem to ask for ideas, with no hint which ones would be good or bad, how to judge better from worse.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! Hope you don't mind me editing your question just to make it a bit more readable. Feel free to take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site.

Comment: I'm going to have to vote this as too opinion-based. There's not really a right answer, and from the information you're giving us, I instinctively want to suggest a reorganization of your system, which is simultaneously an answer, but I guarantee is not the kind of answer you want, thus making it too broad of a question. Perhaps maybe try to narrow down the details so that we can see better what you're working with?

Comment: Yes i did think it more like an idea. But perhaps I should have asked  to help me decide if it would be more likeable for them to act as a group only while there need to make next generation of there species. That is the only thing that comes to my mind. Could that be more like the question i should ask?

Comment: Again, too opinion-based. What may be likable to me may not to you or to F1Krazy or to Molot.

Comment: I've submitted an edit which i think helps clarify the question to hopefully bring it away from the realm of opinion. I understand what youre trying to ask, but I'm also having trouble phrasing it in a way that doesnt appear opinion on the surface. Hopefully we can help get you an answer and get it phrased appropriately for the site :) welcome to SE.WB!

Comment: Welcome to the site! I have to agree with @SoraTamashii. My first reaction to this is try to recategorize, something using Venn diagrams of basic traits. But which traits are used and what to call the resulting groups would be _primarily opinion-based_.

Comment: does your ecosystem have a non-predatory base, a food chain needs a producer to support it.

Comment: @TheStwor -- Glad you recognise this as a bit of an idea trawl. I'm with Molot on this one: your query is definitely on topic, but is really too broad. (And I'm usually quite liberal with allowing for opinion based queries!, so for me to close, that's saying something.) Stack Exchange really isn't the place for tossing ideas around and it's not for helping people to decide which choice to make. There are plenty of worldbuilding and constructed culture forums out there that are discussion based and where that kind of query is more welcome. Try to focus on one specific issue only!

Answer (score 4):

> **Live plants** mostly act like "sand traps" eating any flesh given to them (...) I need to some how limit them from destroying a large amount of land at once.

"Live plant" is a misnomer. Being lifeforms, plants are by definition living beings just like animals<sup>[citation needed]</sup>.

Other than that, carnivorous plants are a thing in our world. In some forrests and jungles you can find many venus flytraps and other species. The bigger ones will feed on rodents and frogs, even. The very largest one may as well be *Puya chilensis,* which attracts sheep that then get stuck in its spikes and die, fertilizing the soil with their corpses. These buggers have so far failed horribly in *"destroying a large amount of land at once"*.

If your carnivorous plants can move around, then they are no different from regular predators. If they hunt by making traps as you suggest, then they are like antlions and spiders, although their prey may be quite larger.

Comment: Thanks, that could just do the work! :D

Comment: 'Live plants' as opposed to dead plants? I think you're right in that carnivorous plants is probably what was being described.

Answer (score 3):

**You want to protect your world?  Isn't that what "Nature Protector Animals" are supposed to do?**

[image: whale eats fish]
https://www.nwf.org/Magazines/National-Wildlife/2015/AugSept/PhotoZone/Brydes-Whales

You have already in your list a class of creatures which "protect the nature" and eat magic and small animals.  You are worried that your magic bug swarm will destroy the nature.  I observe that the swarm is both magic and small animals - delicious!  I propose that when the bugs start doing their thing, large Nature Protector Animals of various sorts will arrive in short order and devour them.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking who would eat the "small" animals?

If they are like IRL rats or mice, they should be eaten by same predators that eat larger animals. IRL, wolves and foxes and various wild cats eat both large animals like deer, and small animals like rats or mice.

In your world, it sounds like "nature protectors" serve the same role, since they already eat mid-sized herbivores.

Comment: Hi @Bald Bear, If you are unsure of what the question is specifically asking, you should attempt to get clarification from the asker in their question's comments. As is, it seems like your answer is trying more to make sense of the question than it is answer it, which is still not a bad thing, but may ultimately end up being wrong for what the asker's needs are. Just thought I'd point that out.

Comment: Thanks, that did help a bit. But I was asking for a time period in which they cold be peace full and not active as a group or perhaps the opposite. I need to specify period of a time in which they are not threat to the land. But your answer could have just solved my problem, because now I can imagine a scenario in which there is a hunting season and their number get reduced.

Answer (score 2):

So you have a group of probably aggressive plants that like to eat meat.  Look at the carnivorous plants that exist in the real world.

The sort of it, as far as I understand, is that real carnivorous plants live primarily in nutrient poor soil.  What they eat is still the energy from sunlight to make sugars, but they need more than that.  Meat provides that supplemental nutrition.  So that's *why* they eat animals.  Nature provides us another example in common weeds.  One aggressive weed will choke out competing plants in the same patch of soil.

That'll give you some *Why*'s for why your Live Plants doing what they do.  It can also give you some directions in limitations.

Soils throughout the world vary a lot, depending on a variety of conditions.  That alone gives you a very solid reason for limiting the range of your very hungry plants.  Perhaps they initially grew in areas that are swampy.  That means they aren't going to spread readily toward more well drained soil.  The water requirement may be too high.  Maybe they evolved in an area that had highly acidic soil, like azaleas or roses.  Those won't thrive unless you give them some specific types of fertilizers to alter the pH of the soil they are in.  That give you another reason to limit range.

The types of local animals are equally influenced by the local plant life which is in turn influenced by soil.  So you get low grasslands.  In turn you will probably get relatively small animals like mice and voles and bunnies.  If those are the predominant animal, the Live Plants will evolve to eat the most common animals, which aren't that big to begin with.

Hopefully that'll get you where you need to be.

Comment: Yes, like i said, those are just some of the most basic types that I can put them in. 
Thanks, I think that it should be manageable from here.

Comment: You can Upvote and accept the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your creatures sound like magic Locust.

The Locust swarms on earth ebb and swarm based on the availability of food, seasons, and their reproductive cycle.

Have a look at the [Desert Locust (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desert_locust) for ideas.

They reproduce 2 to 5 times in a year, so the swarm or "upsurge" is really the children or great-great-grandchildren of the initial hatching.

This could be a viable mechanism for your creature, especially if you intend to have an ominous stage in your world where the first sightings of the creature cause people to start trying to exterminate as many as possible before its too late to prevent an upsurge.

Answer (score 1):

Food availability, seasons and predation.

Since food availability cant drop too much or it'll mark the land as destroyed you limit them through their magic. Their brand of magic (or all magic if you like) ebbs and flows. This can ebb and flow over time and even vary from location to location. This means they are limited in time and what area they can feed on. Better yet, they might only follow magic around and while they might eat a lot as they pass they dont stay long enough to deal damage.

Seasons. Like any small creature, seasons can heavily influence their number. First food becomes scarcer and then the cold (or heat, depending on the area) kills off a lot leaving few to build up their numbers again.

Predation. As with most creatures that generate lots and lots of offspring, the local wildlife learns how delicious they are quickly. Ducks for example get dozens of ducklings per cycle but only a few make it to adulthood. And whenever a small critter or insect manages a baby-boom, it's predators will shortly after have a baby-boom of their own as food and energy is easily accessible and more predators reach maturity.